# MAMP Bad Gateway when PHP and HTML combined

Tags: php, html, xampp, phpstorm, mamp

I have always used PhpStorm on my PC and have XAMPP working perfectly. I have successfully set up MAMP, with apache and mysql working fine. I have properly configured the CLI interpreter, made a database and everything else that was recommended.

My problem is very weird and I cannot seem to find the solution. 
The problem is as follows:

PHP ONLY pages load fine and behave as expected.
HTML ONLY pages work just fine too, as above.

The issue is that when I try to run a page that has a php script and also displays html, it gives me the 502 Bad Gateway issue (PhpStorm 2019.2.1).

If someone could please help me out that would be amazing, I have a new Macbook and am keen to get everything working as it was on my PC and begin developing my pages as normal.

Thanks a heap everyone!

Comment: Have you same problem with localhost or 127.0.0.1?

Comment: What URL you are trying to use when that 502 happens? I have a bit diff thought on "MAMP" part... ( I mean: maybe it's not MAMP at all...)

Comment: That's a seemingly known problem with PHP builtin web server being used through PHpStorm. Are you positively sure you're actually using the Apache server you've installed?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález local host does not connect to anything when its all set up. Not sure why. I am quite an amateur with MacOS.

127.0.0.1 returns "safari cannot open the server"

localhost:8888 connects to the MAMP page showing that it works.

Comment: No idea about MacOS either. But PHP's server has a *Not Found* page that looks [like this](https://i.imgur.com/tC8Otlx.png), that might give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so thanks everyone for helping me out in solving this problem. Heres the problem and solution I found:

MacOS has its own built in apache server that starts automatically.

I disabled them using the following commands, the first should work for most but didn't for me, the second one did work however.

$ sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist

sudo killall httpd

The next part that made it all work was placing my files in the htdocs folder of the MAMP folder.

All of that plus a little bit of configuration in PHP storm made it all work perfectly.

Thanks to all that commented.